# Chartjs using angular doughnut not returning formatter function to display label and value

Tags: angular, typescript, chart.js

I want to display label name and value around the graph near datasets segment. I've written a formatter function and it's not returning. [look into the below link is my requirement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7fi4j.jpg) but however I'm not able return labels and values around the graph [this is what I got but not returning label and values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dYQXw.jpg)

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Chart, ChartOptions, ChartDataset, ChartConfiguration } from 'chart.js';
import 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-your-component',
  templateUrl: './your-component.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./your-component.component.css']
})

export class YourComponent implements OnInit {
  chart: Chart;
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.createChart();
  }
  createChart(): void {
    const data: ChartDataset[] = [
      {
        data: [10, 20, 15, 5, 50],
        backgroundColor: [
          'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
          'rgb(255, 159, 64)',
          'rgb(255, 205, 86)',
          'rgb(75, 192, 192)',
          'rgb(54, 162, 235)',
        ],
      },
    ];

    const options: ChartOptions = {
      plugins: {
        datalabels: {
          formatter: function (value, context) {
            const label = context.chart.data.labels[context.dataIndex];
            return label + ': ' + value + '%';
          },
          anchor: 'end',
          align: 'end',
          offset: 10,
          color: 'black',
          font: {
            size: 12,
          },
        },
      },
    };

    const config: ChartConfiguration = {
      type: 'doughnut',
      data: {
        datasets: data,
        labels: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'],
      },
      options: options,
    };

    const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;

    this.chart = new Chart(canvas, config);

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [*chartjs-plugin-datalabels* documentation](https://chartjs-plugin-datalabels.netlify.app/guide/getting-started.html#registration), you need to register the plugin globally or locally].

Register globally:

```
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

Chart.register(ChartDataLabels);
```

Or register locally:

```
import ChartDataLabels from 'chartjs-plugin-datalabels';

const config: ChartConfiguration = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    datasets: data,
    labels: ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Blue'],
  },
  options: options,
  plugins: [ChartDataLabels] // Register locally
};
```

[Demo @ StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-4n7jbe?file=src%2Fmain.ts)